# confused about varieties of linseed oil

Tags: oil-paint

I am fairly new to oil painting. Please explain the differences between refined linseed, cold-pressed linseed, boiled linseed, double-boiled linseed, etc. I am confused with the variety and would like to know the drying times and how these affect the quality of the painting?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a painter in any sense of the word. Using a search engine, I found [**this site**](https://www.cassart.co.uk/blog/how-to-oil-painting-mediums.htm). While not being exhaustive, it explains some of the information interesting to you.

> **REFINED LINSEED OIL**

> This is the most popular form of oil medium. It **slows down the drying time of the paint**, and when painting in layers, this can be very useful. Apply the ‘slow over fast rule’ – paint your fast-drying layers first, and then each layer on top should take longer to dry than the previous one. You can therefore apply more of this medium with each layer.

> The *[brand name]* Refined Linseed Oil **increases gloss and transparency** as well as **smoothing the consistency of oil paint**.

---

> There is also a Cold Press Linseed Oil by *[brand name]*, which is a high quality oil often used when grinding pigments, to create oil paint at a professional level. It **dries more slowly** than Refined Linseed Oil, taking **up for four days**, and **has a shinier and harder finish**.

---

Other information can be found using search engines. If you want to actually improve your painting skills, you might want to attend some classes led by a professional.